# Как вернуть пользователю его сообщение telegram bot python?

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telebot, aiogram

Смотрите у меня такая проблема.
Что если я хочу чтобы простой эхо бот возвращал мне не только текст сообщения, а весь содержащийся контент.
Использую Python3 + aiogram, но если есть решение на других библиотеках, тоже напишите, т.к они все очень похожи.
Первое что пришло мне на ум:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo(message: Message):
    await message.answer(message)
```

тогда при отправке сообщения с картинкой (картинка с подписью сверху) получаю в ответ словарь:
"message_id": 8, "from": {"id": мой айди, "is_bot": false, "first_name": "Fedorgg", "username": "fedorgeogar", "language_code": "ru"}, "chat": {"id": 838910080, "first_name": "Fedorgg", "username": "fedorgeogar", "type": "private"}, "date": 1595711503, "text": " текст сообщения", "entities": [{"offset": 0, "length": 2, "type": "text_link", "url": "url картинки"}, {"offset": 2, "length": 9, "type": "bold"}, {"offset": 12, "length": 14, "type": "italic"}, {"offset": 132, "length": 5, "type": "hashtag"}]}

Как сделать чтобы возвращалось точно такое-же сообщение, как то которое отправили?

Answer (score 1):

Используется библиотека Telegram Bot API . Привожу пример отдельных функций для разных типов контента(но если вы это скопируете в ваш код , всё будет работать):

```py
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.token)

    #Для фото
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['photo'])
    def echo_photo_bot(message):
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id,message.photo[0].file_id, message.caption)

    #Для сообщений
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
    def echo_text_bot(message):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,message.text)

    #Для документов
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['document']
    def echo_document_bot(message):
        bot.send_document(message.chat.id,message.document.file_id)

    #Для аудио
    @bot.message_handler(content_types=['audio']
    def echo_audio_bot(message):
        bot.send_audio(message.chat.id,message.audio.file_id)

    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Из [документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/telegram/types/message.html#aiogram.types.message.Message.answer) следует, что в метод `Message.answer()` нужно подать строку как атрибут `text`.

[Пример `echo` бота из документации](https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/echo_bot.html).